# how to correctly implement UIWebView 'didFailLoadWithError' alert view?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, uiwebview

I want my UIWebView to display an alert view error message when there's been a disruption or disturbance with the load, I've tried implementing the following code, but its been unsuccessful:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
         myAlert.showViewController(myAlert, sender: self)
    }
```

is there something invalid about this method and if so how should I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace: `myAlert.showViewController(myAlert, sender: self)`

With this: `self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)`